Should RDS Proxy Connection Be Initialized Inside or Outside the Lambda Handler?
I'm working on an AWS Lambda function that connects to an RDS database through RDS Proxy. I understand that AWS recommends placing resource-heavy initializations, such as database connections, outside the Lambda handler to take advantage of the Lambda Execution Context and improve performance by reusing connections across function invocations.
However, I’d like to clarify a few points:
Should the RDS Proxy connection always be initialized outside the handler, or are there scenarios where it’s better to do it inside the handler?
What are the key differences between initializing the connection inside vs. outside the handler? For example, how does this impact cold starts, connection pooling, or reconnection logic if the database connection times out?
Are there any specific best practices or things to watch out for when connecting to RDS Proxy from Lambda? For instance, connection limits, retries, or timeout settings that might cause issues under high load.
I’d appreciate it if anyone could share their insights or examples of how they’ve handled similar setups. Thank you!
Looking forward to your advice!
